# midioutshortmsg no sound

Tags: c#, audio, visual-studio-2015, midi, winmm

So I'm trying to play single notes in C# using midiOutShortMsg().  The problem is that no sound is played.  The one way I've figured out to play the note is by putting the midiOutShortMsg() in a for loop from i=0 to 10000.  But I don't believe that's how the API is supposed to work.

Later in the project I want to implement the MIDI into a Kinect project, and having the for loop delays the real-time feedback of the Kinect.  So the for loop method is a no-go.

Below is the code I am using to play notes, if you comment out the for loop then no sound will play.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace MIDITest
{

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MidiOutCaps
    {
        public UInt16 wMid;
        public UInt16 wPid;
        public UInt32 vDriverVersion;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,
           SizeConst = 32)]
        public String szPname;

        public UInt16 wTechnology;
        public UInt16 wVoices;
        public UInt16 wNotes;
        public UInt16 wChannelMask;
        public UInt32 dwSupport;
    }

class Program
    {
        // MCI INterface
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern long mciSendString(string command,
           StringBuilder returnValue, int returnLength,
           IntPtr winHandle);

        // Midi API
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern int midiOutGetNumDevs();

        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern int midiOutGetDevCaps(Int32 uDeviceID,
           ref MidiOutCaps lpMidiOutCaps, UInt32 cbMidiOutCaps);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern int midiOutOpen(ref int handle,
           int deviceID, MidiCallBack proc, int instance, int flags);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern int midiOutShortMsg(int handle,
           int message);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern int midiOutClose(int handle);

        private delegate void MidiCallBack(int handle, int msg,
           int instance, int param1, int param2);

        static void Main()
        {
            int handle = 0;

            var numDevs = midiOutGetNumDevs();
            Console.WriteLine("You have {0} midi output devices", numDevs);
            MidiOutCaps myCaps = new MidiOutCaps();
            var res = midiOutGetDevCaps(0, ref myCaps,
                   (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(myCaps));

            res = midiOutOpen(ref handle, 0, null, 0, 0);

            byte[] data = new byte[4];

            data[0] = 0x90;
            data[1] = 50;
            data[2] = 111;
            uint msg = BitConverter.ToUInt32(data, 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                // both hard coding the message and creating it with byte doesn't work
                //res = midiOutShortMsg(handle, 0x007F4A90);
                res = midiOutShortMsg(handle, (int)msg);
            }
            res = midiOutClose(handle);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that this approach is misguided. Use an existing MIDI library to do this. I have a lot of respect for [naudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio). It already contains a managed wrapper for MIDI IO that should be well-tested. Why don't you use it instead of wasting a huge amount of time on writing a midi wrapper, worrying about byte ordering and the like? It will save you a ton of time and has universal app support out of the box. You can [nuget it into your project](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio/) easily.

Comment: Hi spender, thank you so much for your response!  I've been working with naudio all day today, but I found that playing single notes also require the use of System.Threading.Thread.Sleep().  And I am getting the same issue where playing a single note will halt the whole program and no sound is played.  Would you happen to know any workarounds?

Comment: It seems Your sound is starts playing... for a little time, but you Close the driver.
If You do not want to wait, then use timing: Start a sound, go elsewhere, and when the time has come, come back, and stop that sound, and/or start another. If your program is over, close the device.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `midiOutShortMsg` does not stop the execution of the code, meaning that `midiOutClose` gets called before the note has had time to play.

One way to overcome this would be to add a `Sleep`:

```
res = midiOutShortMsg(handle, (int)msg);

if (res == 0) // Check success code
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(length);
}

res = midiOutClose(handle);
```

Where `length` is the amount of time in ms it takes for the note to finish playing.

However this is almost certainly not reommended.

Comment: Doing anything with normal windows timers with MIDI will give timing so sloppy that it would be recognizable to even the most musically illiterate.

Comment: Thanks for your response Bassie!  Unfortunately with System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(), it halts the whole program since the Kinect is single threaded by default.  I am looking into multithreading, but the kinect updates at 30 frames per second, I don't want to accidentally create crazy amount of threads and was just wondering if you knew other workarounds!

Comment: @Shinsuke No problem - you could check if the application is outputting any sound, and don't call `midiOutClose` until the sound is no longer playing.